# Rails: Can't get mailer to work when I set credentials as environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, actionmailer

I setting up a contact form in my Rails 4 app, that will send emails using Gmail. First, I got it to work with these settings in config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'myusername@gmail.com',
  password:             'MyPassword',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Then I used [this](https://richonrails.com/articles/environment-variables-in-ruby-on-rails) approach to setting environment variables in config/environment_variables.yml and loading it with config/initializers/environment_varibles.rb, and changed the SMTP settings in config/environments/development.rb to:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

My config/environment_variables.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
  GMAIL_USERNAME: myusername@gmail.com
  GMAIL_PASSWORD: MyPassword
production:
  GMAIL_USERNAME: myusername@gmail.com
  GMAIL_PASSWORD: MyPassword
```

Now, the mailer serves me the error "Net::SMTPAuthenticationError". What I find very strange is that the environment variables seems to be loaded fine when I start the server. I check this in the rails console:

```
2.3.0 :001 > ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]
 => "myusername@gmail.com" 
2.3.0 :002 > ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
 => "MyPassword"
```

I have switched back and forth between the working hard coded original solution and the non-working environment variable solurion. I have double checked the spelling of the credentials several times. I have looked for a solution for two days, and I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple.

Does anyone have a clue of what the problem might be? :-)

Comment: ok, so add `puts ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` in development.rb file and see what it prints .. which will ensure what value it has there.. let me know what you see. Another way to ensure this, hardcode the username and password and see if it works well or not. if it works well, that means your approach of fetching those values are not correct. BTW, you need to set those environment variable in the machine before rails boots.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm sorry, i don't know where a `puts` line in a config file will be printed, but I tried to put `<%= ENV["GMIL_USERNAME"] %>` in a view, and it printed nothing. So I guess you are on to something. I have tried hard coding the credentials in development.rb, and that works fine.

Comment: ok, what os you are using? Your test proved that the way you are setting value to environment variables are wrong.

Comment: if you are on Unix/Linux types of machine, then run `export GMAIL_USERNAME=<value_to_set>` and same way set it for password.. and restart the app. Then use `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` and `ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]` inside the smtp configuration like you have now.

Comment: I'm actually working remotely on the Cloud9 IDE (http://c9.io), but I think they run Linux VM's

Comment: This is very strange. the `export` command before restart didn't help. The `<%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>` in a view prints nothing. But still, the variables are printed when I enter `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` and `ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]`in the Rails console (as described in my original post). Where is the console getting the variables from if they're not available to the mailer or the viev?

Comment: Well, I then might need to see your rails app to figure out. Probably you are doing something wrong, but you don't know that and that is why you are not telling it. real eyes might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue searching for a fix for Rails 6 since the `ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME']` approach doesn't work.

What did work was putting the credentials in my `config/secrets.yml` file (not checked into source)

```
production:
  secret_key_base: xxxxx
  gmail_username: email@domain.com
  gmail_password: password
```

Then in `config/environments/production.rb` I have the following blocks

```
 # Use SMTP for emailing for now
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

 # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'yourdomain.com',
    user_name:            Rails.application.secrets.gmail_username,
    password:             Rails.application.secrets.gmail_password,
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Comment: you can even check in the credentials now, only keeping a local master key :) https://web-crunch.com/posts/the-complete-guide-to-ruby-on-rails-encrypted-credentials